# If the data inside the document is updated or changed, can it be displayed only updated or changed in table on website?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I would like to know in React Firebase can do when data within a document is updated or changed.
Will it be able to show just the updated or changed data in the table on the website?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly so yes, React Firebase is able to show just the updated or changed data in a table on the website. This can be done by listening to real-time updates from the Firebase Firestore database and updating the state in React whenever the data changes.

Comment: it should look smth like this
   
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = db.collection('yourCollection').onSnapshot(snapshot => {
      setData(snapshot.docs.map(doc => doc.data()));
    });

    return () => unsubscribe();
  }, []);

Comment: Hey @SmbatPoghosyan you should write an anwser based on your comments :-)